# Engine RPM continuously rising when using A/C in my Nissan Terrano Diesel

Tags: ac, nissan, diesel, rpm, terrano

My Nissan Terrano Diesel has this weird problem. Whenever I turn the AC on, after a few minutes, the engine RPM continuously rises at shoots up above 3000RPM apprx at idle.

Only when I apply brakes, it comes down. Or only if I turn off the Ac and Blower, it stops.

Comment: When you release the brakes do the revs increase again?